# Nodejs- Unable to get access token from a 3rd party Auth Server using OAuth

Tags: node.js, authentication, oauth-2.0, oauth, authorization

This is my first attempt at connecting using a custom oAuth as i couldn't find a library for the particular service i am working with. Users from my app should be able to authenticate using another service provider like google/facebook. After going through the docs, i was able to mock up something like this to get the access token .

```
export async function getTokens({
  code,
  clientId,
  clientSecret,
  redirectUri,
}: {
  code: string
  clientId: string
  clientSecret: string
  redirectUri: string
}): Promise<{
  access_token: string
  expires_in: Number
  refresh_token: string
  scope: string
  id_token: string
}> {

  const url = "https://api.specificservice.dev/oauth/v1/token"
  const values = {
    code,
    client_id: clientId,
    client_secret: clientSecret,
    redirect_uri: redirectUri,
    grant_type: "authorization_code",
  }

  try {
    const res = await axios.post(url, querystring.stringify(values), {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
      },
    })
    console.log(res.data)
    return res.data
  } catch (error: any) {
    console.error(`Failed to fetch auth tokens`)
    throw new Error(error.message)
  }
}
```

After that i thought that i needed to provide a route that would allow a user initiate this flow.

```
app.get(`/${redirectURI}`, async (req, res) => {
    const code = req.query.code as string

    const { access_token } = await getTokens({
      code,
      clientId: CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: CLIENT_SECRET,
      redirectUri: `localhost:2000/${redirectURI}`,
    })

    // Fetch the user's profile with the access token and bearer
    const epicUser = await axios
      .get(
        `https://authurlfromspecificservice`,
        {
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${access_token}`,
          },
        }
      )
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res.data)
        return res.data
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(`Failed to fetch user`)
        throw new Error(error.message)
      })
  })
```

This did not work as expected because the access token wasn't returned. What do i do next?

Comment: Do you see any errors during the access token retrieval stage?

Comment: Yes. 'Failed to get token ' logged to the console. Thought i got the steps right. am i missing something??